# Database to datatable and show links for results

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset

I have this problem :

I have a Database with some tables,im filling a dataset with all the info and posting it on the gridview.

The whole idea is a search in a user database, what i want to do now is exclude the info from the dataset use the ID from the table so i can redirect the search results to a new profile, which has to be  done by a link.

So what i want is to get the results in hyperlinks which onclick they redirect the user to the profile.

This is a web app.

```
namespace DisplayingImages
{
    public partial class WebForm7 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i=0;
            DataTable PassRecord = new DataTable();
            String str = "select First_Name,Surname from ID where (First_Name like '%'+ @search +'%' ) OR (Surname like '%'+ @search +'%') OR (Email_Account like '%'+ @search +'%')";
            SqlCommand Srch = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            Srch.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            con.Open();
            Srch.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = Srch;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();       
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `ExecuteNonQuery` when you use `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a empty dataset. You have to fill it otherwise you will have an empty gridview.

```c#
da.Fill(ds);
```

Like Soner said you dont have to use ExecuteNonQuery. Use ExecuteQuery instead. 
ExecuteQuery : when you are selecting data from the database then use this 
ExecuteNonQuery : when you are inserting or updating data into database then use this

There is a RowDataBound event which you might already use. 
I can't see that from this piece of code. 
But in there you have to fill the link. 
In case you dont have it then here is an example.

In the frontend you do something like this

```html
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="Gridview_RowDataBound">
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Hyperlink runat="server" ID="link" />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in the code behind.

```c#
protected void Gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   
    //Get data row view
    DataRowView dataRow = ((e.Row.DataItem)DataRowView);
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var link = ((HyperLink)e.FindControl("Link"));
        link.Text = "some text";
        link.NavigateUrl = String.Format("{0}?id={1}", page, dataRow.ID);
    }
}
```

I have done this like out of my head so it isn't exactly copy paste but you get the idea. 
You could also bind an onclick event but that would make it a bit more difficult. 
In the target url you can use the querystring to read the id and get the data from database again.